# Java Application using semantic web

Tags: rdf, jena, owl, semantic-web, owl-api

I would like to validate my understanding about developing an app using Semantic Web.

I am about to write an application in Java, where I will be able to create empty ontology.
Then when user is registered and logged in, will be able to provide some data about himself (eg. skills he has, project that he is working on, people he knows, etc...) Then as another user I want to find some information about my colleagues.

1. For developing such app I can use OWL-API, which allows me to create an ontology, manipulate  and find some data. Is there any query language, which allows me to find some data in that ontology, or like in relational databases - some ORMs? Maybe it is better to use Jena framework for that?
2. Could you advise if it is a right approach to implement such application? Maybe there is some ready tool for such use cases?
3. Do you know any worth recommending resources about OWL and Semantic Web?

I would be very grateful if you could awnsers to my questions, thanks!

Comment: 1. For OWL there is nothing in particular at least no official query language, but there is some API which support DL Query - otherwise, use SPARQL via Jena although some OWL construct are quite verbose in RDF and SPARQL is primarily the query language for RDF and not OWL.

Comment: 2. there is no tool and this is opinion based and a bad question for StackOverflow. Some people use framework X and others framework Y, depending on their skill and preferences. In the end, I personally would most likely use Jena via SPARQL or write Java code that uses OWL API. Or use OntAPI which is an API that combines both APIs

Comment: 3. also, not a good question for StackOverflow. There are dozens of tutorials, MichaelDeBellis has some [blog](https://www.michaeldebellis.com/blog) and there are also good books (but I always keep forgetting their names